# What child does not inherit semaphore adjustments from its parent (semop(2)) mean?

Tags: c, unix, ipc, semaphore

This line in the fork([doc](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork)) man got my attention:

- The child does not inherit semaphore adjustments from its parent (semop(2)).

What does it mean?

This program(code below) would never print "End (child)" :

```
 #define SVID_SOURCE 1
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <sys/ipc.h>
 #include <sys/sem.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/wait.h>
 #include <unistd.h>

 int main(int argc, char **argv) {

   struct sembuf operation;
   int semid = semget (getpid(), 1, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
   semctl (semid, 0, SETVAL, 1); 

   if (fork() == 0) {
      sleep(1); // Let the father do semop()
      operation.sem_num = 0;
      operation.sem_op = -1;
      operation.sem_flg = 0;
      semop (semid, &operation, 1);
      printf("End (child).\n"); 
      exit(0);
   }

   operation.sem_num = 0;
   operation.sem_op = -1;
   operation.sem_flg = 0;
   semop (semid, &operation, 1);
   wait (NULL);
   printf("The end.\n");

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Basically, semaphore adjustments are reset in the child.

Comment: A clear explanation or example would be really helpfull

Comment: Why do you think the code would print `End (child).`?  What value do you think the semaphore has when the child attempts its _semop()_ and why do you think that would succeed?

Comment: According to the docs i thought if the child doesn't inherit semaphore adjustments from its parent, then the code would print `End (child)` (semaphore value would still be 1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first place, there are two independent semaphore subsystems: old-style System V semaphores and POSIX semaphores.  Do not be confused by the fact that both are part of POSIX.  The ones relevant to the question are System V semaphores.

The [`semop(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/semop) syscall is the one used for manipulating values in a system V semaphore set.  A process that modifies a semaphore set via this function can do so in a way that is automatically undone when the process exits, by including a particular flag (represented by `SEM_UNDO`) among the  arguments.  This causes a set of "semaphore adjustments" for that semaphore set to be associated with the process.  It is these adjustments that are not inherited across a fork, and that makes sense because if they were inherited then the undo would be performed twice -- once when the child exits, and once when the parent exits.

POSIX semaphores are generally considered to provide a much better API, and generally they should be preferred over system V semaphores, but it's helpful to be aware of both.

Comment: It's very clear, thanks. They should have included this in the docs.